# Genesis themes: how do alter the markup of post meta on archive pages?

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I'm creating a site based on studiopress's executive pro theme. I'd like to remove the comment count that shows in the post meta in archive pages.

In a conventional WordPress workflow I would child the theme and edit the php directly.

In this particular case, I can't find the markup.

Is the post meta generated from a php template or a function? Where is it, and how can I alter it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your Executive Pro theme's `functions.php`, you can add a function that filters the post info.

In Genesis `lib/functions/post.php`, you'll find a `genesis_post_info()` function, and one particular line in it is:

```
$filtered = apply_filters( 'genesis_post_info', '[post_date] ' . __( 'by', 'genesis' ) . ' [post_author_posts_link] [post_comments] [post_edit]' );
```

That means you can filter `genesis_post_info`, and not include the `[post_comments]` (and `[post_edit]` as that is available from the admin toolbar anyway) part of it.

```
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'gmj_remove_comments_count' );
/**
 * Remove comments count and Edit link from post info.
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235203
 */
function gmj_remove_comments_count() {
    return  '[post_date] ' . __( 'by', 'your-theme' ) . ' [post_author_posts_link]' );
}
```